# The open loop transfer function of a unity feedback control system is given as \$G(s) = \frac{as+1}{s^2}\$

Tags: control-system

The open loop transfer function of a unity feedback control system is given as \$G(s) = \frac{as+1}{s^2}\$. What value of 'a' will give a phase margin of 45° ?

\$G(s) = \frac{as+1}{s^2}\$

\$Transfer\$ \$function\$, \$T(s)=\frac{G(s)}{1+G(s)*1}\$

\$T(s)=\frac{as+1}{s^2+as+1}\$

\$T(s)=\frac{as+1}{(s+\frac{a}{2})^2+1-\frac{a^2}{4}}\$

\$T(s)=\frac{as+1}{(s+\frac{a}{2})^2+\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{4}}\right)^2}\$

Let, \$\omega=\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{4}}\$

\$T(s)=\frac{as+1}{(s+\frac{a}{2})^2+{\omega}^2}\$

\$T(s)=\frac{a(s+\frac{a}{2})+(1-\frac{a^2}{2})}{(s+\frac{a}{2})^2+{\omega}^2}\$

Comment: It could be helpful to add some text to explain the passages. I can't understand at first sight what they lead to.

Comment: 1. Why are you analyzing the *closed-loop* transfer function and 2. Why have you made that strange substitution for ω?

Answer (score 1):

The phase margin of a *closed loop system* is defined at it's gain crossover frequency which is calculated for it's *open loop gain* (as pointed out by [MikeJ-UK](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/2234/mikej-uk)). The gain crossover frequency is when the magnitude gain of the open system is unity. Positive values of gain and phase margins would indicate that the given *open-loop system* is stable when a feedback loop is added to it.
$$|G_{open}(j\omega)| =1 $$

Now you need to obtain the angle at which this happens. For that just take the inverse tangent of the numerator and denominator angles and subtract them, 
$$ \theta = \arctan (N(j\omega)) - \arctan (D(j\omega)) $$

Now to calculate the phase margin use the following equation:
$$ \phi = 180^\circ + \theta $$

When you calculate this way, you'll get the value of 'a'

Comment: You have correctly said that the magnitude of the loop gain is 1 at the frequency of interest, but on the next line you have analyzed the *closed-loop* gain.

Comment: The closed loop gain is used for [calculating crossover frequencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_margin) and hence the stability of the _closed-loop system_, isn't it?

Comment: Look at the last line of the first paragraph, then the second paragraph of that wikipedia article, where it references the [loop gain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_gain)

Comment: Yes, I think you're correct. Figure I've embarrassingly forgotten some basics. I'll edit my answer.